# Блюр картинки при скроллинге страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

нужно сделать, чтобы при скроллинге веб-страницы какой-то объект блюрился. То есть чем больше проскролена страница, тем сильнее заблюривался объект.

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/GVpywz - так ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такой вариант?

```js
let docH = $(document).height() - $(window).height(),
    blur;

$(window).on({
    'scroll': function() {
        blur = Math.floor((1 - (docH - $(this).scrollTop()) / docH) * 10); // Где 10 - это конечная "степень блюра" в конце страницы.
    $('.blur').css('--blur', blur+'px');
    },
  'resize': function() {
        docH = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1500px;
}

.blur {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  -ms-filter: blur(var(--blur, 0));
  filter: blur(var(--blur, 0));
}

.blur img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="blur">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/o2W6F4f.png">
</div>
```